# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "column_name" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I have the following error inside Heroku logs after I run `pgbackups:restore`:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "column_name" does not exist
```

When I run command `pgbackups:restore`, it seems that command breaks/deletes database. After I run that command, Heroku displays me the following message:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I've done the following steps:

```
1. pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U username -F c -b -v -f "Name_development.psql" Name_development
2. Uploaded it to Dropbox
3. heroku run rake db:migrate
4. heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://dropbox/link'
5. After that I receive that error
```

If I run only `heroku run rake db:migrate`, site opens normally. The only problem is there is no data inside tables.

What could be a problem? How can I transfer my data to Heroku and don't break site?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

When I try to restore database with some GUI tool everything works fine.

Comment: run rake db:migrate after restore database

Comment: @VijayChouhan, but that deletes my restored database and now I have empty database again.

Comment: You took a look at here right? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export